# What is correct way to get AssemblyInformationalVersion from assembly in MSBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild

GetAssemblyIdentity task seems to return me only AssemblyVersion, not AssemblyInformationalVersion.

I can parse AssemblyInfo.cs, as suggested by here [Reading AssemblyInformationalVersion value from AssemblyInfo file with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073582/reading-assemblyinformationalversion-value-from-assemblyinfo-file-with-regex) but I don't think this is optimal solution.

Comment: Correct? Depends on your usecase. Your question says reading from assembly, the link you provides read it from AssemblyInfo.cs. What is your intention?

Comment: My intention is to read from Assembly. I don't think that parsing something with RegExp is optimal solution

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to read the AssemblyInformationalVersion from the binary assembly file or from the AssemblyInfo.cs source file? Your question indicates both could be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the `AssemblyInformationVersion` value from the actual assembly binary, your question, as it is currently written, suggests this is the case (hinting at the `GetAssemblyIdentity`-task).

If so, just use [`FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx) and read the `ProductVersion` property. To invoke this from inside MSBuild you probably need a small custom task, that does that.

Internally, that is what the C# compiler [turns the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630055/21567).

If, you need to parse the source code (e.g. of `AssemblyInfo.cs`) for its value (which is a totally different thing!) and the Regex-approach you linked to is not versatile enough for your purposes, you'll have to resort to using Roslyn, or some other technology that actually understands C# and can properly parse the source code.